# supertest gets timeout error when I use await in a controller

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Product = require('./../model/product');
router
  .route('/api/product')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.find({});
    console.log(product);
    return res.status(200).send({ message: 'ok' });
  })

module.exports = { router };
```

the code above is my controller file

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('./../../app');

it('creates a product and product list is emply', async () => {

  await request(app).get('/api/product').expect(200);
});
```

and this is my test file.
when I run the test I receive this error:

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."